# EnableQuery doesn't work for same functions but different endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

Some of my endpoints are wrapped with `[EnableQuery]` decorators. The first one I have is

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery(PageSize = ITEMS_PER_PAGE)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAsync()
{
    var projects = await _projectRepository.GetAllAsync();
    return Ok(projects);
}
```

while the second one is

```
[HttpGet("TestName", Name = "TestName")] 
[EnableQuery(PageSize = ITEMS_PER_PAGE)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetTest()
{
    var projects = await _projectRepository.GetAllAsync();
    return Ok(projects);
}
```

As you can notice, their bodies are the SAME, same repository and same function. However, the first endpoint returns me a json that looks like

```
{
    @odata.context: "https://localhost:44327/api/$metadata#Project",
    @odata.count: 64,
    value: [20],
    @odata.nextLink: "https://localhost:44327/api/project?$count=true&$orderby=CreateDate%20desc&$skip=40",
}
```

while the second one returns

```
[
{},
 .
 .
 .
{},
]
```

or those `@odata.x` things aren't present. I'm not that familiar with `[EnableQuery]` and `OData` but somewhere in the code I found this

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Project>("Project");
    builder.EntitySet<Project>("TestName");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(50);
    endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "api", GetEdmModel());
});
```

`Project` is a class I have that represents a database model and the controller name is `ProjectController`. I've seen multiple documentations online that inherit from `ODataController`. However I don't do that in my case. How can I make the second endpoint work like the first one? I also couldn't find that much info about `builder.EntitySet<Project>("TestName");`, can someone explain to me what this is? Should "TestName" be the name of the endpoint?

Comment: You can check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdXaH.png). The difference between use `HttpGet` and `HttpGet("TestName", Name = "TestName")` is that: using the `HttpGet("TestName", Name = "TestName")`, we need to add the `TestName` at the request url path. More detail information, see [HTTP verb templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#http-verb-templates)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I'm aware about this but when I add `TestName` at the request url path, I don't get `@odata.count, @odata.context` and `@odata.nextLink`. The `?$top=2&$orderby=...` works fine. What I'm trying to achieve is get the `@odata.x` props